# Current flow from pull-up resistor in MCU

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, pullup

[image]
According to the circuit diagram here, when the switch is on, the current directly flows to the ground, but shouldn’t it split at the junction and some of it go to the MCU, as well as the ground, if so then I don’t think MCU will give LOW as output?

I may have some mistake in understanding the concept of pull-up resistors.

Comment: This looks like an *input* pull-up - why would there be a switch on an output pin? If that pin is actually an input and is pulling down, it would be in parallel with the switch, so when the switch closes the current would indeed split, but think about the resistance of the closed switch vs. the resistance of the circuitry in the micro making the logic low level...

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! There is a part of your question that could be explained better. What do you mean by "MCU will give LOW as output"? Are you asking about an output function as well as an input pin?

Answer (score 1):

The digital inputs on most microcontrollers and logic ICs sense the voltage, and pass very little current.

In your drawing, if the switch is closed, the MCU will see Zero volts, so will sense a logic Low.  Some very small current may flow out of the MCU pin, through the switch, to Ground.

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t think MCU will give LOW as output?

I believe you mean "MCU will read LOW on the input".

To get an answer I suggest calculating [voltage divider](http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/voltage-divider-calculator) output using 0.1 Ohm as switch resistance (R2) and comparing resulting voltage to Vil (maximum input voltage considered LOW) from your MCU datasheet

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right (except that this is no MCU output configuration). There might be some current flowing into the MCU pin. But if the MCU internal resistor is very high (like >100kOhms), the current flowing into the MCU pin is very little compared to the switch and R1 current. In fact, it is so little that you may disregard it.